# oracle plsql parameter default null

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

i have to use parameter in a column and column is not nullable. but parameter will be by default null. how do i control the null value. 
because when i am not giving value, it is considering value as null and my script is getting failed. would appreciate your help
example -

> create procedure test1    (p_1 number default null) 
>   as 
>   begin 
>   select col1, col2 from table1 
>   where col1=p_1 -- default NULL;
>   end; 
>   /

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Well, what value do you want to put in the column if one isn't supplied in the call? You have to have something to use instead of null. Or do you want to select all values if the argument is null? (You also have to select *into* something...)

Comment: hi alex, if i dont put any value, statement wll just ignore and execute without where conditions. basically i have to use 2 parameter, 1 i will put value and another one is default null. so it will be like ,,,,, whrere col1=p_1 and col2 = p_2. and p_2 i will put value and p_1 will be default null

Comment: Alex, i am using collection in into clause

Answer (score 1):

Option 1.-
where (nvl(col1, '[NULL]') = nvl(p_1, '[NULL]'))

Option 2.-
where (nvl(col1, '[NULL]') = coalesce(p_1, col1, '[NULL]'))

Width any option the query is a bit more expensive to resolve.

Option 1.- returns the values requested, and null values on a null request.

Option 2.- returns the values requested, and ALL values on a null request.

Replace the '[NULL]' value width an unexpected value of that type and situation, for indexes, can be 0 (cero) or -1 (negative), for dates you can look for '01/01/0001' (an unexpected date), for strings you can look for '<%[NULL]%>', but if your parameter value can have any value of the domain, you may look for, or combine with, a second column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `or` to make the query filter conditional:

```
select col1, col2
bulk collect into some_collectin
from table1
where p_1 is null or col1 = p_1
```

If `p_1` is null, either because no argument was passed or the argument was null, then the first part matches - for all rows. If it is not null then the first part does not match for any rows, so the equality check applies and filters for only the rows that do match the argument.

If you have other conditions then remember to use parentheses to make sure the overall logic is right:

```
where (p_1 is null or col1 = p_1)
and ...
```

Comment: it worked alex. thanks a lot. i was struggling since morning.